# Codeigniter - If query returns something, do something

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a function in my model that is supposed to check my database to see if a particular username already exists. If so, it should call itself again with an incremented value of `$appendDigit` (which is then added to the end of the `$string` and checked again). Otherwise it should just return the original `$string` as the `$username`.

---

### Controller

```
$string = strtolower($value['first_name']) . '_' . strtolower($value['last_name']);
$username = $this->ums_model->checkIfLoginExists($string, 1);
```

---

### Model

```
public function checkIfLoginExists($string, $appendDigit)
{
    // When first called, appendDigit will be equal to 1. 
    // If the username already exists the method will call itself, 
    // incrementing the appendDigit until it finds an unused username

    if ($appendDigit != 1) {
        $username = $string . $appendDigit;
    } 
    else {
        $username = $string;
    }

    $this->db   ->select('username')
                ->from('users')
                ->where('username', $username);

    $result = $this->db->get()->row_array();

    if (!empty($result)) {

        $appendDigit++;
        $this->checkIfLoginExists($string, $appendDigit);

    }

    return $username;

}
```

---

This works fine for unique usernames but not if the username already exists (I get a duplicate entry database error). So I presume the `if (!empty... )` statement is not working properly. I've tried all sorts of variations with `result_array()`, `row()`, `result()`... but nothing seems to work.

I thought I might need to put the `return` into an `else` block but when I do that it always returns `NULL` no matter what.

What am I missing here?

---

**Update:** When I do a `var_dump($result)` this returns

```
array(1) { ["username"]=> string(11) "original_string" }
```

So it looks like my query is fine too.

Comment: in php string concatenation is done with a dot `$string . $appendDigit;`. With `+` won't work as expected

Comment: Of course, I knew that! (doh). The issue isn't resolved though, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by returning `$appendDigit` to the controller instead of the `$username`. I could then add an if/else to the controller:

```
$appendDigit = $this->ums_model->checkIfLoginExists($string, 1);

if ($appendDigit == 1) {
    $username = $intranet;
}
else {
    $username = $intranet . $appendDigit;
}
```